# Await on abstracted asynchronous task

Tags: c#, async-await, task, abstract

I am very new to the `async/await` usage. I am trying to abstract the asynchrony and `await` conditionally in the UI. I have an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract bool IsRunning { get; }
    public abstract Task<bool> Run();
}
```

and from it some derived instances, first one being synchronous:

```
internal class Derived1 : Base
{
    private readonly Base baseCase;
    private Task<bool> task;
    public Derived1(Base baseCase)
    {
        this.baseCase = baseCase;
    }
    public override bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
    public override Task<bool> Run()
    {
        task = new Task<bool>(() => 
        {
            bool ok = DoSomething();
            return ok;
        });
        return task;
    }
}
```

and a derived class for an asynchronous implementation:

```
internal class Derived2 : Base
{
    private readonly Base baseCase;
    private Task<bool> task;
    public Derived2(Base baseCase)
    {
        this.baseCase = baseCase;
    }
    public override bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return task != null && task.Status == TaskStatus.Running; }
    }
    public override Task<bool> Run()
    {
        task = new Task<bool>(() => 
        {
            bool ok = DoSomething();
            return ok;
        });
        return task;
    }
}
```

Then in the UI, I would like to `await` on `asynchronous` task (if user specified so in a run-time config), as follows:

```
internal class CaseMenuHandler
{
    private async void OnRun(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (var case in Cases)
        {
            Base baseCaseRunner = GetCaseRunner(case);
            try
            {
                bool ok = true;
                if( something_holds ) {
                    ok = await baseCaseRunner.Run();
                }
                else {
                    ok = baseCaseRunner.Run().Result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogError(...);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this is clear. Can I do the above, specifically awaiting conditionally inside an if block? Ideally I would like to make the `Base` class only return `bool` and not `Task<bool>` for the `Run` method, and only have the `Derived2` class override to return a `Task<bool>`, but I am not clear on how to do that. Perhaps I should return the `task.Result` inside the `Run` method of `Derived2`? If there's a better way to this including the abstraction or any other corrections,  please let me know. Appreciate any ideas.

**EDIT #1**

The `Run` method form for the synchronous implementation in `Derived1` has been clarified in the responses below. I am not allowed to change the signature of the `DoSomething` method though, so given that, my `Run` method in `Derived2` (asynchronous implementation) looks as follows now (thanks to @Stripling's comments):

```
    public override async Task<bool> Run()
    {
        task = new Task<bool>(() => 
        {
            bool ok = DoSomething();
            return ok;
        });
        task.Start();
        return await task;
    }
```

**EDIT #2**:

When I try the above (also tried putting a `task.Start()` call after the `task` definition, I get the following error:

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Application accessed domain object from a thread other than a legal thread.
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in high-level terms?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: Let me try. I am trying to have an abstract class and one derived class which implements some methods asynchronously while the other derived class doesn't, and then in the UI to conditionally await depending on which case I'm in.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-1-inheritance-and-interfaces.html

Comment: WRT edit #2: you're trying to do something with an object that only wants to be accessed by a specific thread. This sort of thing often happens in applications with a designated UI thread. It's hard to know exactly how to help you without knowing what line of code is causing the error.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: I'm trying to debug further, but so far, does the usage in Edit #1 look OK?

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: I'd use `return await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());` for simplicity. But yeah, you've got the right idea, assuming that DoSomething really needs to run on a separate thread.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: From debugging the error is displayed immediately after I step over the return statement (in Edit #2), control is not even passed back to the UI calling method. I see the following in the Output log, not sure if both are relevant (at least the second one might be):     1. A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll; 2. First-chance exception at 0x000007fedd0cfd7f in MyApplication.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I do the above, specifically awaiting conditionally inside an if block?

You *can*, but you shouldn't have to. If you do things right, there's no great advantage to specifically invoking a synchronous task in a blocking fashion: as a general rule, you can just `await` the Task that's returned, and if it represents a synchronous task then the `await` will be resolved synchronously with very little overhead.

When I say "if you do things right", here's the right way:

```
// synchronous
public override Task<bool> Run()
{
    var result = DoSomething();
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}


// asynchronous
public override async Task<bool> Run()
{
    var result = await DoSomethingAsync();
    return result;
}
```

`await`ing the result of the first example above will not do any thread-switching or anything like that. `await`ing the result of the second might, depending on the implementation of `DoSomethingAsync()`. There's no particular need for a layer of abstraction: you can always check a `Task` to whether it's completed or not, and `await`ing an already-completed task will always return a value immediately.

Comment: Thanks, good to know that I could use await on any Task. Then I don't even need the if-condition.

Comment: But what if for the asynchronous Run method in your example, I am unable to use await on DoSomethingAsync as you did (i.e., I don't want to use async keyword rather return just Task<bool>) since my Task is defined using a lambda function. I guess my question then is how to use async/await keyword if I need to use a lambda function to instantiate the Task?

Comment: I found the answer to my question above. See my edit #1. I will test this and get back shortly.. thanks

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: Why are you defining your Task with a lambda? Do you need it to run on a separate thread? Why? Is it a long-running CPU-bound task, or is it doing something that should be asynchronous for which you don't have any Async library methods available?

Comment: Yes, it is long running which is why we need it to run asynchronously. I tried what I had posted with the edits, but it doesn't seem to work. While I am able to do other stuff with the application, it doesn't actually run the asynchronous task. And when I added the task.Start(), it gave me the cross-thread operation error.

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: Is there any way to separate the operation that's causing the error away from the code that's performing the long-running operation? Also, my guess is you'll want to use `Task.Run(() => DoSomething())`. It's simpler than creating a new task and then having to remember to Start it.

Comment: I finally managed it, but had to refactor internals quite a bit to isolate like you & StephenCleary mentioned the synchronous components. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how your synchronous version is synchronous, you still use the `Task.Run(`, I would have expected

```
internal class Derived1 : Base
{
    private readonly Base baseCase;
    private Task<bool> task;
    public Derived1(Base baseCase)
    {
        this.baseCase = baseCase;
    }
    public override bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return false; }    

    }

    public override Task<bool> Run()
    { 
        bool ok = DoSomething(); 
        return Task.FromResult(ok);
    }
}
```

If you do it that way instead of the way you are doing it, your other code just becomes

```
private async void OnRun(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    foreach (var case in Cases)
    {
        Base baseCaseRunner = GetCaseRunner(case);
        try
        {
            bool ok = true;
            ok = await baseCaseRunner.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogError(...);
        }
    }
}
```

The asynchronous version will run asynchronously and the synchronous version will run synchronously.

Your "async version" is not really async either, see [Stripling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37817123/80274) for the correct way to do that method.

Answer (score 2):

> Then in the UI, I would like to await on asynchronous task (if user specified so in a run-time config)

First off, I just have to say that this is a really bad idea. Some things should be configurable, and some should not. The asynchrony of operations should not be configurable. Period. This is a horrible design, and the first thing I would do is push back hard against ridiculous "requirements" like this. It literally makes the same amount of sense as a configurable flag for whether or not to throw exceptions.

That said, it *can* be done. It's painful, difficult to maintain, and *completely useless* at the end of the day. But hey, I assume you're getting paid for this so it's all good, eh?

If you **must** do this for political reasons (there are absolutely no valid technical reasons), then I recommend you use the [Boolean Argument Hack from my article on brownfield async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx). One problem with just blocking (`Result`) is that it doesn't work if `Run` uses `await` (for [reasons described on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)).

The boolean argument hack simply adds a boolean argument indicating whether the method is expected to complete synchronously or not.

```
public abstract class Base
{
  public abstract Task<bool> RunAsync(bool sync);
}
```

The semantics here are that if `sync` is `true`, then the task returned from `RunAsync` *must* already be completed.

Your implementation then looks like:

```
internal class Derived1 : Base
{
  public override async Task<bool> RunAsync(bool sync)
  {
    IsRunning = true;
    try
    {
      if (sync)
        return DoSomething();
      return await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
    }
    finally
    {
      IsRunning = false;
    }
  }
}
```

And it's called like:

```
private async void OnRun(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  foreach (var case in Cases)
  {
    Base baseCaseRunner = GetCaseRunner(case);
    try
    {
      bool sync = !something_holds;
      bool ok = await baseCaseRunner.RunAsync(sync);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      LogError(...);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that it can always be *called* with `await`, but `OnRun` will actually be *synchronous* if `sync` is `true`. This is due to the "await fast path" - the fact that [`await` *first* checks whether the task is already complete, and if it is, it continues *synchronously*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (as described in my async intro blog post).

Comment: Is it a bad idea to have a Task object as a private member in a class? In all the examples I've seen, it is like you've shown and looks like you were able to capture the IsRunning status as well. But is this equivalent to having a private Task object to check the IsRunning status? Also could using your approach potentially fix the error I am getting in Edit #2? The error happens when returning from the Run method.

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: It's not *bad* to have `Task`s as members, but to have a `Task` member that represents the execution of a method in that same class is rather odd. It seemed unnecessary to me. The cross-threading error will probably still happen; if you can't use thread pool threads (as the error would suggest), then you'll need to modify `DoSomething` to be asynchronous (and take a `bool sync` parameter).

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: It seems like you've got two different approaches, and the proper solution depends on which approach is necessary. **If** you have an interface with a method that may be implemented synchronously or asynchronously, then `Task.FromResult` is a great solution for the synchronous implementation. **If** you have a configurable parameter where the *calling code* needs to enforce whether the *called code* is synchronous or asynchronous, then the boolean argument hack is appropriate.

Comment: I thought I fixed it, but spoke too soon. I even stripped the DoSomething of everything, just to debug, and simply returned true inside DoSomething just to debug, but even that resulted in the cross-threading error immediately on return await task in the Run() method. The DoSomething method doesn't have async in its signature. Does it have to? One of the things we wanted to avoid was to cascade the async all the way down all callees

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: If `DoSomething` has no code, it shouldn't cause a cross-threading error. I recommend you remove code until you have a minimal reproducible test case, and then post that as a separate question.

Comment: You're right.. I was able to make it work by removing all code from DoSomething.. so now I am pursuing some ideas based on that knowledge.

Comment: After drilling down, and moving some of the code so it executes it synchronously, I have isolated only long running code so that DoSomething only instantiates an object of a class (BatchEngine) which has an Execute method which is actually running a (batch) process, using Process.Start(), and it also writes to a file using File.WriteAllText(). My question is if all I had in DoSomething was the call to the BatchEngine class Execute method, then I shouldn't expect the cross-thread operation error, right? Should I move the File.WriteAllText call from the Execute method? If it helps I can re-post

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: cross-thread exceptions are only caused by thread-affine components.

Comment: I am guessing this means 'Process' is thread-affine. With just the Process in the method, it always result in this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Task.FromResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx) to return a task that contains the result that was computed synchronously, and await.

```
bool ok = DoSomething();
return Task.FromResult(ok);
```

As a side note I'd not put synchronous code in a method that was generally intended to be asynchronous (or that is synchronous in other classes/places) and vice versa. I'd use different interfaces/base classes for a synchronous and an asynchronous implementation.

```
interface IRunnable
{
    bool IsRunning;
    bool Run();
}

interface IRunnableAsync
{
    bool IsRunning;
    Task<bool> RunAsync();
}
```

Comment: The `task.Result` is not nessesary, he can just await it like a normal Task and get the result.